# Typescript union type of functions weirdly becomes an intersection type of the arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, data-modeling, union-types, mapped-types

I'm trying to model my data in Typescript in the following manner. Main focus is the type `MessageHandler` that maps the `type` in a message with a callback that accepts that message. I followed the [handbook chapter for mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

```js
type BaseMessageBody = {
    msg_id?: number;
    in_reply_to?: number;
};

type BaseMessage<TBody> = {
    src: string;
    dest: string;
    body: BaseMessageBody & TBody;
};

type BroadcastMessage = BaseMessage<{
    type: 'broadcast';
    message: number;
}>;

type InitMessage = BaseMessage<{
    type: 'init';
    node_id: string;
    node_ids: string[];
}>;

type Message = BroadcastMessage | InitMessage;

type Body = Message['body'];

type MessageHandler = {
    [M in Message as M['body']['type']]?: (message: M) => void;
};
```

So far so good. The expanded type of MessageHandler is

```js
type MessageHandler = {
    broadcast?: ((message: BroadcastMessage) => void) | undefined;
    init?: ((message: InitMessage) => void) | undefined;
}
```

But when I try to actually use the type like below:

```js
const handlers: MessageHandler = {};

export const handle = (message: Message) => {
    if (message.body.type === 'init') {
        console.log('Initialized');
    }
    const handler = handlers[message.body.type];
    if (!handler) {
        console.warn('Unable to handle type', message.body.type);
        return;
    }
    handler(message); //Error here
};
```

I get the following error. Somehow the handler type has transformed to `const handler: (message: BroadcastMessage & InitMessage) => void`

```bash
error: TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type 'Message' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BroadcastMessage & InitMessage'.
  Type 'BroadcastMessage' is not assignable to type 'BroadcastMessage & InitMessage'.
    Type 'BroadcastMessage' is not assignable to type 'InitMessage'.
      Types of property 'body' are incompatible.
        Type 'BaseMessageBody & { type: "broadcast"; message: number; }' is not assignable to type 'BaseMessageBody & { type: "init"; node_id: string; node_ids: string[]; }'.
          Type 'BaseMessageBody & { type: "broadcast"; message: number; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ type: "init"; node_id: string; node_ids: string[]; }': node_id, node_ids
        handler(message);
                ~~~~~~~
```

There are slightly related questions on stack overflow but I wasn't able to resolve my problem by following them. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgWQghcDmEYHsAmIUAvFAN4BQAkALYKYD6AlvgPwBcUAdgK40BGEAE4Buaky4MhEMABsQDYLg7c+g0RQC+YiqEixEKNBmwAeACp5CAPhLlqCIQGNOCYEImYxVfGmCv3T29+AhBOeCRUdCwcUKgAMihLULFtCl1waBghXDh8J0RgKJNoUgijaLNKKj0ITgByfhy8grd67xpjGM5eAWFU6x1aqABJLiYiruw7cuKY02rahokJ9uouAghmfACPLi91ze2EXc8AbQBdAaHMqDnpsub8wvvoAB9R8cnKiBv9KyIpFeZ0aoXqV3Sw1eAAk4Fx8LJhHZqmdkFAJHcptBEHcQSFCOCQbVwRcVAAKTo-TjIACUJFsADdcCxUjonLguG4oAALOEI4QnTE-WHwxFCZFpCgQAAeYFwQmAUHZnMVvNFpSgFKx1KxdOItmqTAAZprKSUAHT4kDm4bEO1QeorYD1OnVKjKhC4RHm2S4TBk+pjCZMOCyJgALwg+Bd3k01A9qr5Yrsav5QgQZzNMUtoRtmQhVGNmoAhKmxa7qO6OZ7vQB3OBCLgBgCqXDg-ERUCUPKT0GJABooFnsDnCHnIDTvFRpMAeI3Y9QAPSLgBiTHTirAOQ7EBo7GoZeEWp+k60YiAA) is the playground with all the code.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to clearly ask a single question; everything starting with "additionally" looks like a separate question.  Also note that your link is just a link to stack overflow and not to any Playground or other IDE.

Comment: (see previous comment) I'm going to assume that the question is everything before "additionally".  If so, then your issue is that TS doesn't have direct support for what I call "correlated unions" as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). The recommended fix is refactoring as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NVYQMw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes that answers my question completely. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have direct support for what I call "correlated unions" as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The compiler can only type check a block of code like `handler(message)` once.  If the type of `handler` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions like `((message: BroadcastMessage) => void) | ((message: InitMessage) => void)` and the type of `message` is a union of arguments like `BroadcastMessage | InitMessage`, the compiler can't see that as safe.  After all, for *arbitrary* `handler` and `message` variables of those types, it could be a mistake to allow the call; if `message` were of type `InitMessage` but `handler` were of type `(message: BroadcastMessage) => void`, you'd have a problem.  The only safe way to [call a union of functions is with an intersection of its arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), not a union of its arguments.  A union argument could turn out to be the wrong type for the union function parameter.

In your case it is, of course, impossible for that failure to occur, because the type of `handler` and the type of `message` are *correlated* due to them coming from the same source.  But the only way to see that would be if the compiler could analyze `handler(message)` once for each possible narrowing of `message`.  But it doesn't do that.  So you get that error.

If you just want to suppress the error and move on, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
handler(message as BroadcastMessage & InitMessage); // ‍♂️
```

That's technically a lie, but it is easy.  But it doesn't mean the compiler sees what you're doing as type safe; if you accidentally wrote something like `handler(broadcastMessageOnly as BroadcastMessage & InitMessage)` (assuming `broadcastMessageOnly` is of type `BroadcastMessage` and not `InitMessage`) the compiler wouldn't catch the mistake.  But that might not matter, as long as you're confident that you've implemented it right.

---

If you care about the compiler verifying type safety here, then the recommended approach to dealing with correlated unions is to refactor away from unions and toward [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into simple key-value object types or [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over such object types.  This technique is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  For your example, the relevant changes look like this:

First let's make the basic key-value type we're going to build from:

```
interface MessageMap {
  broadcast: { message: number };
  init: { node_id: string; node_ids: string[] };
}
```

Then you can redefine your `Message` type to take a particular key as a type argument:

```
type Message<K extends keyof MessageMap = keyof MessageMap> =
  { [P in K]: BaseMessage<MessageMap[P] & { type: P }> }[K]
```

If you need your original message types you can recover them:

```
type BroadcastMessage = Message<"broadcast">;
// type BroadcastMessage = { src: string; dest: string; 
//  body: BaseMessageBody & { message: number; } & { type: "broadcast"; };
// }

type InitMessage = Message<"init">;
// type InitMessage = { src: string; dest: string; body: BaseMessageBody & 
//  { node_id: string; node_ids: string[]; } & { type: "init"; };
// }
```

And since `Message<K>` has a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) corresponding to the full union of keys, just `Message` by itself is equivalent to your original version:

```
type MessageTest = Message
// type MessageTest = { src: string; dest: string; 
//  body: BaseMessageBody & { message: number; } & { type: "broadcast"; };
// } | { src: string; dest: string; body: BaseMessageBody & 
//  { node_id: string; node_ids: string[]; } & { type: "init"; };
// }But
```

And `MessageHandler` can be written in terms of `MessageMap` also:

```
type MessageHandler = {
  [K in keyof MessageMap]?: (message: Message<K>) => void;
};
```

Finally, you make `handle` a generic function that accepts a `Message<K>`, and the error goes away:

```
export const handle = <K extends keyof MessageMap>(message: Message<K>) => {

  if (message.body.type === 'init') {
    console.log('Initialized');
  }
  const handler = handlers[message.body.type];
  if (!handler) {
    console.warn('Unable to handle type', message.body.type);
    return;
  }
  handler(message); // okay
  // const handler: (message: Message<K>) => void
};
```

By the time you call `handler`, the compiler sees it as type `(message: Message<K>) => void`.  It's no longer a union of functions; its a single function with a parameter type of `Message<K>`.  And since `message`'s type is also `Message<K>`, the call is allowed.

Is it worth refactoring to this form?  If you're confident that your original version works and will continue to work, it's certainly going to be easier to just assert and move on.  If you're less confident, then maybe the refactoring here is worth the effort.  It depends on your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgPIBOAlgOZ6FFIAuAnjMgEIhQQCy0KCDoQuAewAmbJAF5GzZmCh0A+jUkB+AFzEArmABGEKgG4mimsFVUIMDG1UtxO-UZPnFAX3MXWHbl4BIREIAB4AFQlpAD45BUUkKCp4XSgWWmA6T0TJaBY0jKtsvyJDKTZdHj5BKGFRaJkAMiQoipyiH3w-dk4kLipxEEl0dNr65Hlq4LrQsIJE-05dAHJDQeHRlhWOpRDRXWADYzM-LxjfRV7kAElgGhZx0Pjpp9F50qWIVasHnc-gFIIOpJIVMiVFoC8iCoGDigBtAC6u3Ol2Y1yQb0m-Q2I14j32yAAPkg7g8sWiiBjGvEsfC1hUVsjulcApjCQAJEDASQYEzxBaJeH8JBWdmzURIXiY+nlaRM+nXJmI1wAClIE10-AAlHI4gA3cQaFGUpDwcTAdJIAAW3N5Jlh4omXJ5fKoAq6fggAA8YOIqCwzRarbbXdj1YStYTdbI4oLLAAzJARiUQAB0crYaYxslzSBWv22uvjiXNlvEfLTGHEdFVKzJLBomBoWAgkhW2t2nU+ZZDdrd8VD9qoUHhGtCGYq2YCzMWNCTqoAhEO3cXPkRexX0wB3EBUYB1gCqoEMfNY4ht-eQSoANEhx6JJ9Jp5xO+ukLYWHp912kF5PiuJgphMUpQDiQx4mMhJIC0DZYp2SAAPSIUggB8G4A7LuALAEgBCZIA8H9nGi-5MCQ0BwIgSAAGI0N6jA9GyryEjS8glkQyhqBorhHO4pxztYtj2I4zicccHgESy6L0UEWKRI0cTMZ8ySpEkRRZL+eTpHCqmfJmVRSYxFQwa0jQmuJRBWCwJgJuQTqhPwIAwAkijrBBWy6Lg96Rm4Jx-r+hZucQQIgpp2QBdCGiOuk4JIj5ZymV8NnvAA0kgPoWTyYEANYQGw4hJlidkOfIWU5XlhIFXJnzufCAAKorAEgiWIrpNSEmE+X2TViKGe51y6LV5x-vCjVxchopJjlejEBAbasNa0AQHRfQDC5+JYrSrUAETOZs+IbRcfijdSuJbGtzFJCkwWmEg6kFMp4JXQdKFIDp-R6amNItO5D7fF5Hh-t1Xy6Ftx27VdXSKKNRGsn0cHQfI0kbYWe27IdbKw6mArnUpkXFFdN2Xc9FTNTMEwfUgj1EO5ULAhoBPUzCwVImDAO9UgiP3CwG1gyjKFQxJfRYhE+TramFMYoLwtnYpBP43duPkxDT0vQx70GZ9HmpocIlmP96us8DK3pFzMWK-9JLudLcuqdd+QE8rb2k2rCvMKNeChTToJWyF9PhYzyK627+tI9zFN81SbJYi6w4Cp8Q11UgxW5QlAj2SqujAaEUapmEiUxDGBpGpIJl+L2gaASOWfOle7rMZ6ig+n6AZBpaZdXvEOcpd6aWSJl2VJ+1MAxBnBzJzned6rRc4Lt9T5ZjmeYFhzHaOaWwZblWNZ1g2TYYC2bYdr+-6LKXl5hjXp-DqOM+Zi+ECzok87Jsu1drosG5r5Wu77keJ5ns4F9-wCCsO818pzXDfG-D8EAvw-k+EfRI5dh4QAQqNcQGUQBsE+KNE+5d07fUrnMXO+ckCGg0J8MS3YvBAA)